# MKMapKit Not Showing userLocation

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager, userlocation

I need help with showing the user's location on my MapView. I have done everything I could possibly find online, but it still does not work.

*I have a CLLocationManager in my AppDelegate that calls the locationUpdate in my viewController.*

The `(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location` method gets called every time and the `location` coordinates is correct when logged with the `NSLog().` Still, there is no "Blue Dot" on my iPhone's screen. The region is not set as well.

Please take a look and tell me if I am missing anything.

**This is my header file:**

```
//My .h file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKReverseGeocoder.h>
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    MKMapView *mapView;
}
-(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
-(void)locationError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

**This is my part of my implementation file:**

```
//My .m file
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@implementation FirstViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapView.delegate = self;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;// = {{0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0}};
    location.latitude = -33.8771;
    location.longitude = 18.6155;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = location;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [location coordinate];
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:loc];
    if([mapView showsUserLocation] == NO)
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    NSLog(@"User Loc: %f, %f", mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude,
                     mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"In MapView: %@",[location description]);
}
@end
```

Thank you for your time!
It is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you see any map at all?  Why aren't you doing addSubView on the mapView?  Are you running in the simulator?

Comment: I am seeing the fully zoomed-out world-map. Then zoom in manually to my office. Looks like normal Maps on "Map"-view. The MapView is on one of the Panes on a TabBarController. I am running on both simulator and on my iPhone 4.

Comment: I think the map you see is one you created in Interface Builder but it's not connected to the one declared in your view controller.

Comment: Possible Solution: in my HeaderFile, should "MKMapView *mapView;" not be "IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;" and then I attach the mapView to the MKMapView in IB?

Comment: If you choose to use the one in IB, yes (and remove the alloc+init in viewDidLoad).  Otherwise, delete it from IB and add `[self.view addSubview:mapView];` after the alloc+init in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Funny, my thing did not show your last comment, but I figured that out on my own and it worked. Thank you very much Anna!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Map kit in Interface Builder needs to have the (Find User Location) checked!!